# R Gui app on Mac adds empty line when calling history

Tags: r, rgui

The R Gui app on my Mac has been showing strange behavior lately. Whenever I use curser-up to get an item from the history, the App will add an empty line before the code. For every time I execute and re-call, it will add another. Below a screenshot of how that looks like.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this error, by any chance?

Comment: Doesn't happen with me.

Comment: Still happens for me, even after complete re-install

Comment: For me, this is caused by de-activating the option "Cleanup history entries" in Startup options. Toggled the option on and the problem went away.